Army - shaving with a razor
There are many inspiring stories of Jews who were conscripted, and went to great lengths to get out of doing melacha on Shabbat, eat matza on Pesach etc. There are halachos and responsa dealing with what to do in that situation.
I have never seen any responsa about shaving. Many armies force you to shave with a razor (this came to mind because apparently the UK army recently lifted a ban on beards), and shave off the area of the peyot. Is there any discussion on this?

The armies force them to use a razor? Or the armies force them to remove their beards ? The latter could be accomplished via less problematic methods such as depilatory...

@Deuteronomy I re-read your question. That's the kind of thing I'd expect to be discussed in the sources I seek, thank you.

@RabbiKaii its a question of fact... you state it as fact (in the present tense) that armies force people to shave with a razor... is that so? Do any contemporary armies force people to do so? Genuinely asking, as I do not know what the reality is (my impression is that modern armies do not have such a mandate).

@Deuteronomy a google shows that regulations for shaving are common in militaries, and many will not permit trimmers, and require soldiers to be clean shaven. As for depilatory, that might be allowed on base, but unlikely in combat. Generally on assignments soldiers are given a very strict set of equipment they are allowed to carry. Given this is so easily google-able though, I didn't feel the need to bring a source, but given that you have said it doesn't sound common to you, I'll try and track down an exact regulation that I can cite. You can vote the question closed until then if you like

I'm not interested in closing your question, I think it is interesting and merits exploration and doesn't run afoul of any major issue I can see. I was simply asking what the actual מציאות is. I would be surprised if any modern army banned electric shavers or depilatories (details which are not as readily googalable, and it seemed that you manifestly knew was so, thus the innocent question). Really not a big issue at all... upvote headed your way as a demonstration of good faith.

@Deuteronomy sure, and don't worry my suggestion was equally innocent. I am interested in upholding the rules of MY, because they work for producing good results. Closing a question isn't taken as personal or in bad faith, but an encouragement to improve a question. I understand that in this case, the issue is not close-worthy. I do hope to one day stumble across an example, to make this more than hypothetical and add it in one day. FYI I had googled and found that yes, not readily available, but I saw lots of chatter about it. A solid source would take a bit more work, agreed

Having been in the US army they don't care how you shave as long as it happens. In any scenario where the noise of an electric shaver is a concern the rules in shaving are significantly relaxed out of concern for infections

https://derher.org/wp-content/uploads/Sivan-5783-6.pdf

In מחנה ישראל, the Chafetz Chaim brings this up in 21:9, and suggests that one should try their best to reduce the issur, including asking a non-Jew to perform the shave (without helping at all and remaining completely passive), and trying to find something that cuts less close than a razor blade.
Thanks @Danny Schoemann for remembering the sefer, and @Deuteronomy for finding the link and the page.
